# String slice arguments

Tags: python, string, slice

When `'teststring'[::-1]` reverses the string, why can't we just write `'teststring'[1:4:-1]` when I want output like `'tset'`?

Any good sources to understand memory allocation and objects storage and other sources for python learning?

Comment: in your second snippet you wrote `'teststring'[1:4:-1]`. Do you not see any problem here? Your range is going from 1 to 4 but step is -1. This condition will not ever be fulfilled.

Comment: tset = 'teststring'[3::-1]

Comment: "memory allocation" is an interpreter specific implementation detail and not part of the language. Also how objects are stored is not the part of Python you should start your learning process with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'teststring' [1: 4: -1] This example is incorrect because −1 all it does is return from the initial value to the secondary value and you can not put a smaller number in the first part and say return from 1 to 4

Also to get 'tset' from the 'teststring' string:

```
'teststring'[3::-1]
```